# Map as value in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, thread-safety

I have a `Map` which is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, here is the problem i am wondering.
I have another `Map` inside the `ConcurrentHashMap` which is a regular `Map`. 
Is this circumstances fine for concurrency, or should i have to use `ConcurrentHashMap` for

```
private Map<String, Map<Integer,Float>> calculations = null;
private Constructor(){  
    calculations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
private void foo(){ 
    calculations.add("XXX",new HashMap<>()); // this one ?
    calculations.add("XXX",new ConcurrentHashMap<>()); // or this one ?
}
```

Which implement is correct for concurrency?

Comment: Depending on how you access your map, the map implementation you use is probably irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use ConcurrentHashMaps for the value-Maps as well - the performance penalty is neglible - because you can not guarantee, that the maps are not accessed concurrently.

If only the container map is thread safe, you only have thread-safe access to the container, but you have no thread-safety on the values. In other words, you can not prevent, that two threads get the reference to same value-map and access it concurrently (with at least one thread doing write operations).

For example:

```
T1  T2   HashMap      T3       ContainerMap
 |   |       +<-create-+           |
 |   |       |         +-put(map)->+  //thread safe
 +------get(map)------------------>+  //thread safe
 I<--------------------------------/
 |   +-------get(map)------------->+  //thread safe
 |   I<----------------------------/
 |   |       |
 +-put(v)->--+
 |   +put(v)>+  //concurrent access, not thread safe
```

You'd be fine, if the value maps are immutable (`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`), otherwise you'd risk your threads getting stuck in infinite loops.

An alternative would be to synchronize the access on the value-map (`synchronized(valueMap)`), or use another locking mechanism (i.e. StampedLock for optimistic read-locking).

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you should use `ConcurrentHashMap`, if you aim for multithreading and concurrent modifications from multiple threads and you can't have null values, as `ConcurrentHashMap` cannot have them. Otherwise, you should use a normal HashMap.

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║   Property    ║     HashMap       ║ ConcurrentHashMap ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣ 
║      Null     ║     allowed       ║   not allowed     ║
║  values/keys  ║                   ║                   ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════║
║Is thread-safe ║       no          ║       yes         ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════║
║     Lock      ║       not         ║ locks the portion ║          
║  mechanism    ║    applicable     ║                   ║ 
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╣
║   Iterator    ║     fail-fast     ║    fail-safe      ║ 
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer your question based only on the information that you have given.

The fact that you are storing references to `Map` objects within another `Map` means nothing.  What matters is how your program *uses* any particular map.  IF multiple threads access any particular map object, and IF at least one of those threads *updates* that map, and IF access to that map is not protected by any higher-level locking; THEN *that* map should be a thread-safe implementation such as `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Multiple threads might access at the same object and its Map which is value. My question is this when i am trying to access a key in the container map, does it lock value(referenced Map) or any other thread may access it. If it is locked, i think there is no need for making it concurrent hash map, am i right ?

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu, You can not lock _values_ in Java, and a "thread-safe" container does not confer any thread safety upon the things that you put _in_ the container.